# Proof that $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}((\alpha))=|N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\alpha\in\mathcal{O}_K$, the ring of integers for a number field $K$. I am trying to understand the proof given in Jarvis's Algebraic Number Theory that $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}((\alpha))=|N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)|$.

We let $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathcal{O}_k\omega_1+\cdots\mathcal{O}_K\omega_n$. Then $(\alpha)=\mathcal{O}_k\alpha\omega_1+\cdots\mathcal{O}_K\alpha\omega_n$. By definition of the norm of an ideal, we have $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}((\alpha))=|\mathcal{O}_K/(\alpha)|$.

The following line is what gives me trouble: "if we write $\alpha\omega_i=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ji}\omega_j$, then the index of $(\alpha)$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ is just $|\det(a_{ij})|$". Why is this true?

Comment: I don't know Jarvis' book but does it contain the following formula for the discriminant: $$disc(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)=[\mathcal{O}_K:G]^2 disc(K)$$ where $\alpha_1,....,\alpha_n$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $K$ with all the $\alpha_i$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $G$ is the subgroup of $\mathcal{O}_K$ generated by all the $\alpha_i$? The claim you are asking for will follow from that formula.

Comment: @russoo No, Jarvis's book doesn't contain that result!

Comment: Does the book contain any results on free abelian groups of finite rank?